# Expose hapi plugin methods via server.expose or server.method

Tags: javascript, node.js, api-design, hapi.js

We are using Hapi as our API framework and put everything related to our persistent storage backend (mongo via mongoose) in a plugin. Now I am wondering how to best expose all the CRUD methods for the different collections (users, notifications, purchases, etc.) to our other API plugins.

I know about `server.expose` and `server.method` (Is that just `server.expose` with caching?) and just can't decide which I should go for in this case. Can you make a recommendation?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are not the same thing.

`server.expose` is a way to read or update the exposed values of a plugin. Usually used for communicating state between plugins and/or the main Hapi app.

`server.method` is for exposing methods, and has an ecosystem for handling failure, and as you said, caching.

I think in this case, you would probably opt for server methods.

Comment: Thanks for that, Nuri. Seconds my feeling.